How to find correlation of a set of four variables?
I have a set of four variables (specifically four columns of data) and I am interested in finding some measure of the correlation between them. I know one measure of correlation in this sense would be to use multiple correlation, but I have no preference for the ordering of these variables so I don't know exactly how that would apply here. I was thinking I could take the average of four multiple correlations by regressing each variable on the other 3 separately. Is there a more concrete way to do this?

Why is correlation only defined between two variables?

Can you tell us what is your research question? What does the four variables represent in real life? ...

@kjetilbhalvorsen I have data for a set of subjects and each subject completed four trials (hence the four columns). I am quantifying a property of the movement of each subject on each trial, so there is exactly one numerical value for each subject-trial. I want to gauge how much correlation there is in this value over the trials since in theory this value should be the same for each person.

Please add this new information as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are often seen only by a very few people!
